# I'm getting unexpected Identifier as a syntax error while trying to initialize new project in react-native

Tags: node.js, react-native, npm

emphasized text f:\reactnative\autth\node_modules\react-native\local-cli\cliEntry.js:30
    import type {CommandT} from './commands';
           ^^^^

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
    at new Script (vm.js:74:7)
    at createScript (vm.js:246:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:298:10)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:670:28)
    at Module._compile (f:\reactnative\autth\node_modules\pirates\lib\index.js:91:24)
    at Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:713:10)
    at Object.newLoader [as .js] (f:\reactnative\autth\node_modules\pirates\lib\index.js:96:7)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:612:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:551:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:543:3)
```